# Cross LFS - PPC - Error while compiling

Tags: linux, powerpc, cross-compilation, lfs

I'm trying to build a CLFS for a PPC 8270 processor. All is fine until I use the `make ARCH=powerpc CROSS_COMPILE=${CLFS_TARGET}-` command.

```
CC      arch/powerpc/kernel/align.o
arch/powerpc/kernel/align.c: In function 'fix_alignment':
arch/powerpc/kernel/align.c:704:33: error: variable 'instruction' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

make[1]: *** [arch/powerpc/kernel/align.o] Error 1
make: *** [arch/powerpc/kernel] Error 2
```

In `menuconfig`, I used the default configuration except I choose compatibily with PPC 82XX processor family.

Comment: Do you have `-Werror` in your CFLAGS? (If so, you probably shouldn't except for compiling your own code.)

Comment: We need to know which kernel version you are compiling. You should see "instruction" used in the block `if (cpu_has_feature(CPU_FTR_NODSISRALIGN)) {` after line 704

Answer (score 2):

This appears to me to be a bug in align.c 2.6.39 and previous with respect to GCC >= 4.6. I am guessing that you are building on a recent Fedora that has GCC 4.6 as the default installed GCC. The bug should not appear using GCC < 4.6 IMHO.

The variable "instruction" is declared on line 704 and initialized to zero.
It is then re-assigned on line 746. This re-assignment is not enough to squelch the gcc warning. I verified this behavior by compiling

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    i = 4;
    return 1;
}
```

with `/usr/local/gcc-4.7.0/bin/gcc -Wall -o test test.c` and got

```
test.c:3:6: warning: variable ‘i’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

The variable "instruction" is referenced only in code that is ifdef'ed CONFIG_VSX, so that if you don't have CONFIG_VSX set then you will see this problem when compiling with GCC >= 4.6. Setting CONFIG_VSX should solve the problem. If that is not what you want then try setting CONFIG_PPC_DISABLE_WERROR in menuconfig or use [these](http://blog.droidzone.in/2011/12/03/kernel-compilation-flags-a-pain-in-the-a/) instructions to help you turn off the -Werror or patch the code.

If you do patch the code, consider submitting it to kernel.org as I see that this bug still exists in 3.3

Answer (score 1):

Resolved copying libbfd.2-22.so and zlib.so (renamed to zlib.so.1) to /tools/lib.
Sorry for the stupid error, I thought that files were there already.